# Why MDCSelect:change is not working with javascript for material design

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, material-design, mdc-components

Why `MDCSelect:change` is not working when i call it before appending all options

`MDCSelect:change` is working when i put it after appending list **BUT** UI does not look good.

**Question:** How to make `MDCSelect:change` to working without harming ui look.

It works perfectly when i shuffle the code of those 2 lines

```
$('#select_dropdown').html(usersStr);

initializeSelect();
```

With the above code `select UI` does not look good when you click outside anywhere or simply

for a better view, I have created codepen here: https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/poNmBpm?editors=1010

```js
var selectBoxMap = {};
function initializeSelect(){
       var mdcSelectList = document.querySelectorAll(' .mdc-select');
        if(mdcSelectList){
            [].forEach.call(mdcSelectList,function(el){
                var select = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(el);
                el.setAttribute('ripple-attached', true);
                var dropDownId = $(el).find('ul.mdc-list').attr('id');
                selectBoxMap[dropDownId] = select;
            });
        }

}


$(async function(){

  var results = await $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
var usersStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    var item = results[i];
           usersStr += `<li class="mdc-list-item" data-id="${item.id}" role="option">
                              <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
                              <span class="mdc-list-item__text" data-id="${item.id}">
                                  ${item.name}
                              </span>
                          </li>`
}

initializeSelect();

$('#select_dropdown').html(usersStr);

     for(var key in selectBoxMap){
            if(selectBoxMap[key]){
              selectBoxMap[key].listen('MDCSelect:change', (e) => {
                  alert('dropdown changed');
              });
            }
        }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

</head>


<!-- select dropdown -->

 <div class="mdc-select mdc-select--filled demo-width-class">
         <div class="mdc-select__anchor" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="mdc-select__ripple"></span>
                      <span class="mdc-floating-label">Status</span>
                      <span class="mdc-select__selected-text-container">
                        <span id="" class="mdc-select__selected-text"></span>
                      </span>
                      <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon">
                          <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-inactive material-icons">arrow_drop_down</span>
                          <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-active material-icons">arrow_drop_up</span>
                      </span>
                      <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
                      <ul class="mdc-list" id="select_dropdown"  role="listbox" aria-label="listbox">

                      </ul>
          </div>
   </div>
```

Still i'm looking for solution, please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: still i'm looking for a solution please help me, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi, you are getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` because there is no element inside `select_dropdown`

Comment: @Swati this one https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/xxRvREg?editors=1010 works but ui looks like this  https://ibb.co/vssBpkM i want clean ui with working

Answer (score 1):

I've got the idea from this [link](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/select)

```js
var selectBoxMap = {};
function initializeSelect(){
       var mdcSelectList = document.querySelectorAll(' .mdc-select');
        if(mdcSelectList){
            [].forEach.call(mdcSelectList,function(el){
                var select = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(el);
                el.setAttribute('ripple-attached', true);
                var dropDownId = $(el).find('ul.mdc-list').attr('id');
                selectBoxMap[dropDownId] = select;
            });
        }

}


$(async function(){

  var results = await $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
var usersStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    var item = results[i];
           usersStr = `<li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value=" ${item.name}" role="option">
                        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
                        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
                          ${item.name}
                        </span>
                    </li>`;
                $('#select_dropdown').append(usersStr);
}

initializeSelect();



     for(var key in selectBoxMap){
            if(selectBoxMap[key]){
              selectBoxMap[key].listen('MDCSelect:change', (e) => {
                  alert('dropdown changed');
              });
            }
        }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

</head>


<!-- select dropdown -->

 <div class="mdc-select mdc-select--filled demo-width-class">
         <div class="mdc-select__anchor" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="mdc-select__ripple"></span>
                      <span class="mdc-floating-label">Status</span>
                      <span class="mdc-select__selected-text-container">
                        <span id="" class="mdc-select__selected-text"></span>
                      </span>
                      <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon">
                          <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-inactive material-icons">arrow_drop_down</span>
                          <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-active material-icons">arrow_drop_up</span>
                      </span>
                      <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
                      <ul class="mdc-list" id="select_dropdown"  role="listbox" aria-label="listbox">
          
                      </ul>
          </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: not working and ui still dirty as asked by OP

Comment: yeh it is working fine, but i don't want any default value. in this case we have empty value

Comment: actually, if u check their demo they have also used disabled empty value as the first option.

Comment: "Status" is not default value. It is [floating label](https://material.io/components/text-fields#filled-text-field). Try removing mdc-floating-label element if you don't need it.

Comment: @ashenmadusanka do you have any answer without empty values, because i want to award you the bounty

Comment: @Learner i ve remove the empty value.

Comment: @ashenmadusanka, thank you very much, i have fulfilled my above said words